# Is there any fix to the dark scope in CS:GO OpenGL?

Tags: steam, opengl

when I scope to an enemy my scope get Dark, but if there's no enemy, my scope is OK. is there any way to fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe this is intended.

Comment: no, on the Windows version there's no dark scope :/ it's only doing it on my ubuntu (OpenGL)